# Combine negated characters and capture groups

Tags: regex

### How it works currently

I am able to capture the values between the brackets:

```
[[two b][three c]]
```

The result is

```
two b
three c
```

The RegEx for that

```
\[\[(.+?)\]\[(.+?)\]\]
```

When I use this string

```
[[one a]]
```

Nothing is captured and that is how I expect it. Fine.

### The problem

I combine the strings

```
[[one a]] and [[two b][three c]]
```

This is captured

```
one a]] and [[two b
three c
```

### What I understand

In my understanding there a possible approaches could be to negate the `]]` string. But I don't know how to do this. And I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` char matches any char other than line break chars, and the fact it is quantified with a lazy quantifier does not restrict it from matching basically any char (the matches are searched for from left to right, thus, `[[` matched is the leftmost `[[` and the next `][` is matched regardless if there was a `[` or `]` in between.

So, one approach is to exclude any square brackets between `[[` and `][` using a negated character class `[^\]\[]`:

```
\[\[([^\]\[]+)\]\[([^\]\[]+)\]\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBuns4/2). Here, `[^\]\[]+` that replaced `.+?` match one or more chars other than `[` and `]`.

Another approach is the one you mention, namely, match any chars that do not start `[[` (and probably `]]`, too) before `][`:

```
\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\]
\[\[((?:(?!\[\[|\][\]\[]).)*)\]\[(.*?)\]\]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBuns4/4).

The `(?:(?!\[\[).)*?` part matches any char (`.`), zero or more but as few as possible occurrences (`*?`), that does not start a `[[` char sequence (`(?!\[\[)`).

The `(?:(?!\[\[|\][\]\[]).)*` part matches any char (`.`), zero or more but as many as possible occurrences (`*`), that does not start a `[[`, `[[` or `][` char sequences (`(?!\[\[|\][\]\[])`).

**Depending on the regex flavor, you can get rid of some backslashes in this regex.**